# Send ajax as long as tap is holded - if tap not holded - don´t ajax

Tags: jquery

I am actually adjusting my website to mobile devices and have a problem: I use for certain functions the hover event as "trigger". And now I don´t know how to convert a hover event into a mobile-frindly event. I know the taphold event in my plugin (jquery finger) but that only triggers once and doesn´t tell when the tap ceased to be hold. I would need something like:

```
$("selector").on("as long as tap is hold", function () {

});
```

And for another case I´d need something similar, the only difference is I want something similar to "mouseleave" - just for mobile devices (when user doesn´t hold anymore).

Last but not least it should work for delegated events, too.

jQuery:

```
var myInterval;
var i = 0;
var link;
$(".postimagepic").hover(function () {
    link = $(this).attr("src");
    i = 0;
    myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'somephp.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'user':'loooook',
                'topost':link
            },
            success: function() {

            }
        });
        i++;
        if(i == 30) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}, function () { //That´s why I need to know when not holding anymore
    clearInterval(myInterval);
});
```

Comment: does `mousedown` work for this?

Comment: nope, unfortunately not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `hover()` method is just shorthand for:

`$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );`

and in turn, both `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` are shorthands for

`.on( event, handler )`

so you should be able to do something like this:

```
var myInterval;
var i = 0;
var link;
var postimagepic = $(".postimagepic");

var doAjax = function() {
    link = postimagepic.attr("src");
    i = 0;
    myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'somephp.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'user':'loooook',
                'topost':link
            },
            success: function() {

            }
        });
        i++;
        if(i == 30) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
    }, 1000);
};

// handle both touch and mouse events
postimagepic.on("mouseenter touchstart ontouchstart", doAjax())
            .on("mouseleave touchend ontouchend", function () { 
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            });
```

Since `touchstart` and `touchend` support is shakey I would suggest using some kind of helper library like [JQuery Mobile](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/) that provides normalize events accross all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe jQuery v1.7+ has access to these (among others) mobile touch events: 
**tapstart**

- Fired as soon as the user begins touching an element (or clicking,
  for desktop environments).

**tapend**

- Fired after the user releases their finger from the target element
  (or releases their mouse button on desktops).

**taphold**

- This event is triggered whenever the user taps and holds on the
  target element for at least 750 milliseconds.

So you would need to combine both `tapstart` and `tapend`. If you are asking if the Ajax request can be terminated upon `tapend`, then this is not possible. Once the request is made, it has been made. You can however, in the Ajax callback, check to see if a certain variable is set to true/false, which is set by the the `tapend` event.

Example:

```
//Flag to be set upon touchend event:
var touchEnded = false;

//** Handle TouchStart **//
$("selector").on('touchstart', function() {
  //doAjax(callback)
  callback = function(res) {
    if (touchEnded) {
      return false;
    } else {
      //do logic
    }
  }
});

//** Handle TouchEnd **//
$("selector").on('touchend', function() {
  touchEnded = true;
});
```